# How to set path for uploaded file to anguar file's images folder in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular8

I have done file uploading process using nodejs and angular 8.Now i can move uploaded file to nodejs folder.But i want to move angular assets/images folder.I have tried but not working.So how can i set path for that?

Folder structure:

```
client // angular app folder
  -src
      -images

server //nodejs folder
  -app.js
  -uploads //folder
```

app.js:

```
app.post('/api/upload', multipartMiddleware, (req, res) => {

  var tmp_path = req.files.uploads[0].path;
  var target_path = '../client/src/images/' + req.files.uploads[0].name;

  fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err; 
  fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path);
  });
 });  
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [path NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) to resolve:

```
const path = require('path');

var target_path = path.resolve( __dirname, `../client/src/images/${ req.files.uploads[0].name }` );
```